libinput debounce doesn't work (double clicks instead of clicks)
I have a bad quality mouse (Razer Basilisk V3 X Hyperspeed) that cost way too much money for me to replace it with an even more expensive higher quality mouse, and I'd like to try to fix its issues in the software.
It has many issues:

the faster I scroll, the more likely the mouse is to send two scroll events, one in the correct direction, one in the reverse direction. This means that scrolling really fast cause the scroll container to just shake and remain approximately at the same vertical scroll level. This doesn't happen on Windows (but I don't use Windows).
since very recently, the primary click is doubled more than half of the times, this has made the mouse pretty much unusable
when dragging, the mouse sometimes sends a spurious release event, cancelling the drag mid-way. This is impossible to really debounce, but maybe the software can delay all releases by a few millisecond to check if there's a press just after?

libinput supposedly debounces fast events according to some previous answers on this Q&A, but my issues prove that it doesn't on my computer. How can I configure the debounce delay? I'm running Linux Mint Cinnamon with Xorg and libinput 1.25.0.
